# What structure is this?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

[image]

What is the name of this structure?
It's close to Leucine but I'm not sure.

Comment: This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448) question. We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the problem. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this question may get closed.‎ Please [edit] in your full reasoning or thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all we need to count the number of carbons in the main chain.
In this case there are five atoms so the name prefix will be "penta-".
The main functional group is a carboxyl group on the C<sup>1</sup>.
So the methyl group will be on the C<sup>4</sup> the molecula suffix will be "-oic acid".

Knowing this is pretty simple:

**4-methylpentanoic acid**